# Used paint with the wrong base, will painting with the correct base cover it?

Tags: paint

We did my daughter's room with the color pink carnation semi-gloss. It was a light base. We had to buy a small can of that same color to use around her windows after holes were patched. We got the same color (pink carnations semi gloss) but it was a base 1. Now around the windows is a darker shade of pink carnation. Can I paint over a base 1 with a light base (same color) to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **yes**, you can paint over the recently applied paint with a fresh coat of the proper color. Because your paint has a sheen (semi-gloss) you will need to de-gloss the existing finish with fine sandpaper or other abrasive media, clean well to remove dust, than apply proper paint with a high quality brush. Cheap brush = lame finish.

Answer (score 0):

As the customer, you shouldn't be picking out the base yourself. That's the responsibility of the employee who mixes the paint. If the employee picked the wrong base, you should be able to exchange your quart with one that is mixed correctly.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  The OP wants to know if painting over the incorrect paint will fix the problem, not whether or not you think the store should remedy their mistake.

Comment: It's the correct procedure though. The intent of the poster was to know how to fix the error. The solution is to get the *same* paint that was originally used and paint over the mistake. I admit, I did not answer the literal question, but I answered the intent of the question.